# Rspec - user_path(user) is missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In the browser everything works fine, but the Rspec test fail with this message:

ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil, :locale=>#<User id: 1, email: [...] } missing required keys: [:id]`

My failing test:

```
subject {create(:client)} #from factory_girl

visit user_path(subject)
```

For the test to pass, I have to explicitly write the id: `visit user_path(id: subject)`

The strange thing is that it was going fine before, until I ran a `bundle update` for railties etc. This problem has appeared for my other models as well (Profile, Job, etc).

I failed at finding a solution, any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT** `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
    # all my routes
  end
end
```

`application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end
```

Comment: Somehow it's using your user as a `locale`. Do you have locale scope applied in `routes.rb`? Try posting routes file here.

What about `user_path(I18n.locale, subject)`? (maybe you need to set locale in tests?)

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize the User was used as the locale. `user_path(I18n.locale, subject)`works. But how can I avoid doing this, like it used to be? I post my routes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction